# Perl. Regexp work only once

Tags: regex, perl

I need to process the string with regexp and change x->y if is number around.

**String**: `2x2x2 2x 2x2x 2x2x2x2x2`

**Regexp**: `s/([0-9])x([0-9])/$1y$2/g`

```
my $string = "2x2x2 2x 2x2x 2x2x2x2x2";

$string =~ s/([0-9])x([0-9])/$1y$2/g;

print "$string\n";
```

I expect: `2y2y2 xx 2x 2y2x 2y2y2y2y2`

But result: `2y2x2 2x 2y2x 2y2x2y2x2` (not all 2x2 changed)

What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the below regex:

```
s/(?<=\d)x(?=\d)/y/g
```

Comment: @xdazz.. Can you explain this please??

Comment: @RohitJain This means replace the `x` whose before and after is a digit.

Comment: @RohitJain: `perldoc perlre` and see `Look-Around Assertions`

Answer (score 2):

To be explicit: the reason `"2x2x2"` turns into `"2y2x2"` is that your expression first matches `"2x2"`, replaces it with `"2y2"`, then resumes searching *after* that match was found.  The next bit is `"x2"`, which doesn't match your pattern.

The reason @xdazz's solution works is that look-around assertions don't actually consume characters of the string.  The portion matched in the string is just `"x"`, whenever preceded and followed by numerals.

Incidentally, @xdazz's change from `[0-9]` to `\d` doesn't really change much, but it's slightly different: `\d` will also match other Unicode characters that are considered digits, whereas `[0-9]` only matches the exact 10 characters in the given range.